# Numerically determining the minimum/maximum distance between two ellipses

Tags: mathematical-optimization, geometry, distance

The smaller ellipse is contained within the larger one.
[image: ellipses]

By 'minimum distance', I mean the distance that minimises;

```
Sqrt[(y1 - y2)^2 + (x1 - x2)^2]
```

By maximum, I mean the distance that maximises this, with the constraint that it must be colinear with the center of the smaller ellipse. I've given a rough drawing of these in green and purple, respectively;

[image: estimated min/max]

For finding the minimum, I attempted using `NMinimize`

```
NMinimize[{Sqrt[(y1 - y2)^2 + (x1 - x2)^2], G[x1, y1, X1, Y1, major1, minor1] == 1 && G[x2, y2, X1, Y1, major1, minor1] == 1}, {x1, x2, y1, y2}]
```

but it did not like my constraints. G is the equation of an ellipse;

```
G[x_, y, X_, Y_, major_, minor_] = ((x - X)/major)^2 + ((y - Y)/minor)^2
```

where the parameters for these ellipses are;

```
X1 = 200; Y1 = 110; major1 = 10; minor1 = 8;
X2 = 210; Y2 = 100; major2 = 25; minor2 = 30;
```

I also attempted using `NSolve` with a system of equations, but couldn't get that to work either.

Here's the full code I have;

```
X1 = 200; Y1 = 110; major1 = 10; minor1 = 8;    
X2 = 210; Y2 = 100; major2 = 25; minor2 = 30;
G[x_, y, X_, Y_, major_, 
   minor_] = ((x - X)/major)^2 + ((y - Y)/minor)^2;
G1 = G[x, y, X1, Y1, major1, minor1];
G2 = G[x, y, X2, Y2, major2, minor2];

e1 = Plot[y /. Solve[G1 == 1], {x, 170, 250}, PlotStyle -> Blue];
e2 = Plot[y /. Solve[G2 == 1], {x, 170, 250}, PlotStyle -> Red];
Show[e1, e2, PlotRange -> Automatic, AspectRatio -> 1]
NMinimize[{Sqrt[(y1 - y2)^2 + (x1 - x2)^2], 
  G[x1, y1, X1, Y1, major1, minor1] == 1 && 
   G[x2, y2, X1, Y1, major1, minor1] == 1}, {x1, x2, y1, y2}]
```

#### **EDIT**

As Syed pointed out, there was a typo in the original code (y->y_), as well as the major/minor axes being incorrectly specified in the final line. Now it works fine with `NMinimize`. In case anyone is looking at this in the future, here is the updated code;

```
X1 = 200; Y1 = 110; major1 = 10; minor1 = 8;
X2 = 210; Y2 = 100; major2 = 25; minor2 = 30;
G[x_, y_, X_, Y_, major_, 
   minor_] := ((x - X)/major)^2 + ((y - Y)/minor)^2;
G1 = G[x, y, X1, Y1, major1, minor1];
G2 = G[x, y, X2, Y2, major2, minor2];
NMinimize[{Sqrt[(y1 - y2)^2 + (x1 - x2)^2], G[x1, y1, X1, Y1, major1, minor1] == 1 && G[x2, y2, X2, Y2, major2, minor2] == 1}, {x1, x2, y1, y2}]
NMaximize[{Sqrt[(y1 - y2)^2 + (x1 - x2)^2], G[x1, y1, X1, Y1, major1, minor1] == 1 && G[x2, y2, X2, Y2, major2, minor2] == 1 && (y2 - y1)/(x2 - x1) == (y2 - Y1)/(x2 - X1) && (y1 - Y1)*(y2 - Y1) >= 0 && Abs[y1 - y2] > 0.1}, {x1, x2, y1, y2}]
```

The `Abs[y1 - y2] > 0.1` is a hacky workaround to ensure the maximum length is not passing through the inner ellipse.

The final results;
[image: minimum]

[image: maximum]

Comment: How about using this definition: `G[x_, y_, X_, Y_, major_, 
   minor_] := ((x - X)/major)^2 + ((y - Y)/minor)^2;` ?

Comment: I would use one of the two answers in [228499](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/228499/10397)

Comment: @Syed This fixed my issues with using NMinimize, and I've now got it working, thanks a million. My last line also used the wrong major/minor axes.

Comment: @rhermans I wouldn't know how to apply those to the maximum constraint.

Answer (score 10):

**modified**

Try `RegionDistance`

```
elli1 = ImplicitRegion[((x - 200)/10)^2 + ((y - 110)/8)^2 == 1, {x, y}]
elli2 = ImplicitRegion[((x - 210)/25)^2 + ((y - 100)/30)^2 == 1, {x,y}]

mini1 = NMinimize[{RegionDistance[elli1, {x, y}],Element[{x, y}, elli2]}, {x,y}]
mini2 = NMinimize[{RegionDistance[elli2, {x, y}],Element[{x, y}, elli1 ]},{x,y}]
```

For the maximum constraint we have to define a line through the centroid of elli1:

```
rc1 = RegionCentroid[elli1]
p2 = rc1 + ({x1, y1} - rc1) t1 

maxi = NMaximize[{(p2 - {x1, y1}) . (p2 - {x1, y1}), p2 == {x2, y2}, 
t1 > 1, Element[{x1, y1}, elli1], Element[p2, elli2]}, {t1, x1, y1,x2, y2}]

Show[Map[Region, {elli1, elli2}], 
Graphics[{Blue, Point[rc1], Point[{{x1, y1}, {x2, y2}} /. maxi[[2]]],Red, Point[{{x, y} /. mini1[[2]], {x, y} /. mini2[[2]]}]}   ]]
```

[image]

Comment: Note "maximum  ... with the constraint that it must be colinear with the center of the smaller ellipse"

Comment: @BobHanlon Thanks for your hint, I'll modify my answer

Comment: You might not need the ImplicitRegion's . You could use `Circle[{x,y},{r1,r2}]` and be even more concise.

Comment: ^ though I couldn't get this to work directly myself, I needed to create a function first e.g `rdf1=RegionDistanceFunction[elli1]` instead.

Comment: This looks promising, although I think the definition for t1 is missing from your answer?
As a result I wasn't able to run your code for finding the maximum distance.

Comment: See my edit to the question, I was able to get it to work with NMinimize without needing a region, which ran a good bit quicker than using the RegionDistance. For some reason also, `mini1` in your code came out to be wrong for me? It gave a distance of ~0.124

Comment: @Joe.S `mini1`gives a minimal distance of `2.99` which seems to be correct!

Answer (score 6):

There is an analytic solution for the minimum of your particular ellipses though it's complicated and you're better off with the numerical methods given already, but here's my working:

Start with the parametric form of an axis oriented ellipse where $\mathbf{s}$ gives the sizes and $\mathbf{c}$ is the center:
$$
f(t,\mathbf{s},\mathbf{c})=\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 \cos (t) & 0 & c_x \\
 0 & \sin (t) & c_y \\
\end{array}
\right)\left(
\begin{array}{c}
 s_x \\
 s_y \\
 1 \\
\end{array}
\right),\  0\le t < 2\pi
$$
Let the points on the two ellipses be $\mathbf{p}_1=f(t,\mathbf{s}_1,\mathbf{c}_1)$ and $\mathbf{p}_2=f(u,\mathbf{s}_2,\mathbf{c}_2)$ where $t,u \in [0,2\pi)$

The points $\mathbf{c}_1, \mathbf{p}_1, \mathbf{p}_2$ are collinear when

$$
\begin{vmatrix}c_{1x}&p_{1x}&p_{2x}\\c_{1y}&p_{1y}&p_{2y}\\1&1&1\end{vmatrix}=0
$$
... and we use this to solve for $u$ in terms of $t$ to get $u(t)$. Then we can ask *Mathematica* to find:
$$
t_{\mathrm{min}}=\underset{t}{\mathrm{argmin}}(\Vert\mathbf{p}_2(u(t)) - \mathbf{p}_1(t)\Vert^2)
$$
... which we can use to recover the closest point and min distance. Amazingly it's able to get a symbolic answer, with numerical value about `2.78369`.

```
tmin = 2*ArcTan[Root[640625 + 25000*#1 + 3606250*#1^2 + 9813000*#1^3 + 1938525*#1^4 + 40985280*#1^5 + 34798616*#1^6 + 52344160*#1^7 + 64502386*#1^8 + 30092880*#1^9 + 120859356*#1^10 - 30248400*#1^11 + 80481202*#1^12 - 44183680*#1^13 + 58650200*#1^14 - 38201760*#1^15 + 15191709*#1^16 - 16551480*#1^17 + 5615050*#1^18 - 4075000*#1^19 + 640625*#1^20 & , 4, 0]];
```

Here's the full program -  I convert `Abs->Identity` and use the `SquaredEuclideanDistance` as this helps to simplify the expressions a little and doesn't seem to break anything:

```
Remove["Global`*"]

ellipse[t_, sizes_, center_] := sizes*{Cos[t], Sin[t]} + center
c1 = {200, 110};
c2 = {210, 100};
s1 = {10, 8};
s2 = {25, 30};
e1 = ellipse[t, s1, c1];
e2 = ellipse[u, s2, c2];

(* N.B this has multiple solutions, I choose the first one and remove the generated constant. *)
u1 = FullSimplify[
  First[SolveValues[
     Det[Append[Transpose[{c1, e1, e2}], {1, 1, 1}]] == 0, u] /. 
    C[_] :> 0]]

obj = SquaredEuclideanDistance[e1, ellipse[u1, s2, c2]];
obj = FullSimplify[obj /. Abs -> Identity]

(** (((41+9 Cos[2 t]) (31-36 Cos[t]+5 Cos[3 t] Sec[t]+20 Sin[t]+6 Sqrt[2] Sec[t] Sqrt[Cos[t]^2 (71+29 Cos[2 t]-10 Sin[2 t])])^2)/(2 (13+5 Cos[2 t])^2)) **)

min = Minimize[{obj, 0 <= t < 2 π}, t];
tmin = t /. Last[min]
(** {t->2 ArcTan[5.53…]} **)

N@min
(* {9.09213214869205`,{t->2.7836860115704467`}} *)

(* Check it agrees with NMinimize *)
NMinimize[{obj, 0 <= t < 2 π}, t]
(* {9.09213214869206`,{t->2.783686011570447`}} *)

p1 = ellipse[tmin, s1, c1];
p2 = ellipse[u1 /. t -> tmin, s2, c2];
ParametricPlot[{
  ellipse[t, s1, c1],
  ellipse[t, s2, c2]}, {t, 0, 2 π}, Epilog -> Line[{c1, p1, p2}]]
```

[image: ellipses]

Comment: Cool! Didn't realise there would be an analytical solution
It's interesting that it's a good bit smaller than the minimum I was able to find with NMinimize

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution that minimizes the distance using "Minimize" with conditions.

E.g. for the 2 ellipse:

```
G[x_, y_, X_, Y_, major_, minor_] = ((x - X)/major)^2 + ((y - Y)/minor)^2;
e1 = G[x1, y1, -1, 1, 2, 1];
e2 = G[x2, y2, 2, 2, 1, 2];
```

The expression to minimize and the conditions to apply are:

```
eq = {Norm[{x1, y1} - {x2, y2}], e1 == 1, e2 == 1}
```

We can minimize this by:

```
res = Minimize[eq // N, {x1, y1, x2, y2}]
(*{0.11322, {x1 -> 0.986118, y1 -> 1.11762, x2 -> 1.09629, y2 -> 1.14372}} *)
```

A graphical representation is:

```
ContourPlot[{G[x, y, -1, 1, 2, 1] == 1, 
  G[x, y, 2, 2, 1, 2] == 1}, {x, -4, 4}, {y, -1, 4}, 
 Epilog -> {Red, Point[{{x1, y1}, {x2, y2}} /. res[[2]]]}]
```

[image]

Comment: This works great, I think it's pretty similar to what I was doing, but using Minimize followed by //N rather than NMinimize. I've added more details to the original question, including for using NMaximise to solve for the maximum distance

Comment: This works also with NMinimize and without "//N"

Answer (score 3):

- We write the parametric equation of the outside ellipsoid by parametric `s`, that is `pt2[s]`,  and calculate the intersection points `pt1[s]` of the line `{X1,Y1}`,`pt2[s]` and the inside ellipsoid.
- Here we use `Maximize` and `Minimize`.

```
Clear["Global`*"];
X1 = 200; Y1 = 110; major1 = 10; minor1 = 8;
X2 = 210; Y2 = 100; major2 = 25; minor2 = 30;
pt2[s_] = ({X2, Y2} + {major2, minor2}*{Cos[s], Sin[s]});
sol = Solve[{{x, y} == (1 - t) {X1, Y1} + 
       t pt2@s, ((x - X1)/major1)^2 + ((y - Y1)/minor1)^2 == 1, 
     t > 0}, {t}, {x, y}, Reals][[1, 1]];
pt1[s_] = (1 - t) {X1, Y1} + t pt2@s /. sol;
maximum = 
  Maximize[{EuclideanDistance[pt1@s, pt2@s] // ComplexExpand, 
    0 <= s <= 2 π}, {s}];
minimum = 
  Minimize[{EuclideanDistance[pt1@s, pt2@s] // ComplexExpand, 
    0 <= s <= 2 π}, {s}];
max = maximum // N
min = minimum // N
```

[image]

```
Manipulate[
 Graphics[{EdgeForm[Blue], FaceForm[], 
   Ellipsoid[{X1, Y1}, {major1, minor1}], 
   Ellipsoid[{X2, Y2}, {major2, minor2}], 
   AbsolutePointSize[8], {Green, 
    Point[{pt1@min[[-1, 1, -1]], pt2@min[[-1, 1, -1]]}]}, {Red, 
    Point[{pt1@max[[-1, 1, -1]], pt2@max[[-1, 1, -1]]}]}, Brown, 
   Point[pt1@s], Point[pt2@s], Line[{pt1@s, pt2@s}], 
   Text[N@RegionMeasure[Line[{pt1@s, pt2@s}]], 
    Mean[{pt1@s, pt2@s}], {-1, -1}, pt2@s - pt1@s], Dashed, 
   Line[{{X1, Y1}, pt1@s}]}, PlotRangeClipping -> True], {s, 0, 
  2 π}]
```

[image]